# What does the Scifi & Fantasy stack exchange symbol mean?

Tags: discussion, design

[image]

This symbol is used by the SciFi & Fantasy Stack Exchange.

 
What, if anything, are the meanings behind its component symbols?

Comment: @JasonBaker thanks, tried searching without success. I appreciate being able to see into the dev process of the symbol as well as the meaning.

Comment: @Randal'Thor you said duplicates get downvotes. Withywindle, no offense here, I actually upvoted your question. Then this gets upvotes while other questions get downvotes just because it is a duplicate? And one more thing, I notice this kind of scenarios most frequently to those whose reputations are not yet that high like me. Can you explain now why my question gets downvotes?